# How to write a table from CSV to PDF using Python

Tags: python, csv, pdf

I have a `CSV` file which contains the following table:

```
users        passwords        company
Admin        test_psw         test_cmp
test_user1   test_psw1        test_cmp1
...          ...              ...
...          ...              ...
```

where `users`, `passwords` and `company` are the header of the table and the table itself can dynamically grow up.

How can I write this kind of table to a `PDF` file using `python`? I had a look on `reportlab` library, but came out with no ideas.

Comment: do you need to do any data processing between reading the csv and writing to pdf?

Comment: @joppich No, bu the PDF must be readable and upgradable.

Answer (score 5):

i really like using `pdfkit` for these things.
setup is dead simple, just do `pip install pdfkit` and install `wkhtmltopdf` on your system.

and then from a python-commandline of your liking, do:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('/path/to/your/testcsv.csv',
                 '/path/of/output/testcsv.pdf')
```

more on this [here](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit)

For windows (or if your wkhtmltopdf is not in $PATH), you can provide an optional configuration-parameter:

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/path/to/wkhtmltopdf')
pdfkit.from_file('/path/to/your/testcsv.csv',
                 '/path/of/output/testcsv.pdf',
                 configuration=config
)
```

more on this [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfk) in 'Configuration'-Section.

Comment: it gives me the following error `OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf` Evend after installing  `wkhtmltopdf `

Comment: sorry, updated my answer to point out that dependency. what os are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: provided some additional info, hope it helps. i don't have windows, thus untested

Comment: thanks man, but it gives me the following error: `Loading pages (1/6)
Error: Failed loading page file:///C:/Users/r.spampinato/PycharmProjects/test/reports/1.1-IAM.csv (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.`

Comment: that `--load-error-handling ignore`-thing is remarkably unhelpful, wow... sorry, i'm at a loss here. good luck, though.

Comment: OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''" If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf Evend after installing wkhtmltopdf. Im also getting same error. And Im using Mac OS. Please help