# Convert a csv file to PDF using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-pdfkit

I have a dictionary which I converted to a csv file using pandas dataframe. Below is my csv file:

```
date,time,type,text,start,end,Year,Movies.type
20/10/15,10:00:00,Horror,"adadadasdsfs
sdsdfsdfasdfsfdf 
   fsdfasdfsfsfsdfs",00:00:00,02:59:13,2015,Horror
20/10/15,11:00:00,Horror,"abc",00:00:00,03:00:00,2015,Horror
```

I want this file to be converted to PDF using Python. I found that we can use pyfpdf/pdfkit. In what aspects are they different ?

Which module should I use ? How to convert using that module?

Comment: You can use the `pdfkit` module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48768318/13552470

Comment: Sure I will look into that . Is it possible to do using fpdf ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pypandoc. It can be done like this:

```
import pypandoc

output = pypandoc.convert_file('somefile.csv', 'pdf', outputfile="somefile.pdf")
assert output == ""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is this is specific to .csv files or is it common to .txt, .json  ? What exactly is that assert output=="" mean ?

Comment: My pleasure. You can do this with all the most common file types, including txt. The final line checks that the conversion was successful, and it is not strictly required.

Comment: Here is the official documentation: https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/

Comment: Thanks mate! But currently getting this error :RuntimeError: Invalid input format! Got "csv" but expected one of these: commonmark, creole, docbook, docx, epub, fb2, gfm, haddock, html, jats, json, l

Comment: Possibly happening because of _validate_formats in the pypandoc source code: https://github.com/bebraw/pypandoc/blob/ffe82646d2ab6cc4e732960a1e1af6bfcb760bb1/pypandoc/init.py#L202 . I will try to investigate this error further

Comment: Yeah I will also check with that. Thank you so much!